# OCLint generate html report

Tags: xcode, code-complexity

I'm trying to generate an html report from OCLint analysis. I've installed xctool and generate the json file with this command:

```
xctool -project demoProject.xcodeproj -scheme demoProject -sdk iphonesimulator -reporter json-compilation-database:compile_commands.json  build
```

Now i can run analysis with this command:

```
oclint-json-compilation-database
```

but the report is printed on standard output.

The OCLint scrips has a report-type parameter, so i can create an html report with this command:

```
oclint -report-type html -o report.html
```

but i can't do this with oclin-json-compilation-database.

I read the help page (http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/manual/oclint-json-compilation-database.html) and i found a `oclint_args` parameter but i don't understand how to use it. I tried

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args report-type html o report.html
```

but nothing happens

Answer (score 9):

i found! simply pass all the paramters double quoted

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o report.html"
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do this is:

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -v -- -report-type html -o report.html
```

A more complicated example might look like this:

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -e exclude_this_folder* -e exclude_that_folder* -- \
-report-type html -o report.html -max-priority-2=15 -max-priority-3=30 \
-rc CYCLOMATIC_COMPLEXITY=4 -rc LONG_CLASS=200 -rc LONG_LINE=120 \ 
-rc LONG_METHOD=10 -rc NPATH_COMPLEXITY=20 -rc NESTED_BLOCK_DEPTH=3 \
-rc TOO_MANY_PARAMETERS=5 -rc LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=30
```

Comment: any idea how to exclude system frameworks? I got a lot of errors like `While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/automation/automation/main.m:9:`

Comment: Are you using the 0.9 dev build? It's much better than 0.7.

Comment: i tried that out!! really much better... thanks.. :)